# Code Analysis rule exception cases

Tags: c#, .net, naming-conventions, code-analysis, static-code-analysis

We have CA1709 enabled in our Code Analysis rule set:

> [CA1709: Identifiers should be cased correctly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182240.aspx)

For the most case, it is a great rule to have in place, but sometimes it can be a real pain.

For example, we use the deCarta mapping API and have services such as DeCartaSuchAndSuch.  This results in the following warning:

```
CA1709 : Correct the casing of 'De' in type name 'DeCartaSuchAndSuch' by changing it to 'DE'.
```

Now you can imagine how many times I have to surpress this exact warning.

**Question:** Is it possible to make exceptions for a specific warning?  For example, I want this warning to be ignored for all cases of "DeCarta".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For such cases create a custom dictionary of acceptable, recognized words. You can find the instructions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514188.aspx). For your particular case it could look like this:

```
<Dictionary>
     <Acronyms>
       <CasingExceptions>
          <Acronym>De</Acronym>
          ...
       </CasingExceptions>
       ...
    </Acronyms>
    ...
</Dictionary>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help!

I have found this.

http://dansen.wordpress.com/2008/04/15/suppressing-code-analysis-rules/

it says something like:

When selecting the Project Supressions File option, the SuppressMessageAttribute is placed in the projects GlobalSuppressions.cs file.

```
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

[assembly: SuppressMessage(
"Microsoft.Design",
"CA2210:AssembliesShouldHaveValidStrongNames")]
```

I think that maybe you can do the same with CA1709

I hope this helps ;)

Comment: This will suppress warnings for all incorrect casings, not the ones specifically chosen by OP.